# How do you make calibration boards?

Tags: calibration, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The recommended(8x6) calibration board is so big they won't print on a normal printer. How do you make yours? I'm using a white illustration board then pasting cut-outs of black art papers. In the long run they tend to be curved and my cuts are not that precise which is not ideal in calibration. I'm looking for a better way to have a longer lasting calibration board.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9277/how-do-you-make-calibration-boards?/) by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 475 on 2011-03-03

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A quick solution: Buy a large poster board sheet (something like [this](http://www.staples.com/White-Poster-Boards-10-Pack-22-x-28/product_247403?cmArea=SEARCH)). Then print your checkerboard on A4 (or letter) sized paper. It will get cut across several (usually 4) sheets. The squares along the edges will get cut in the middle, and you can use that to align the 4 pieces properly. Glue the sheets to the cardboard, making sure the edges are aligned.

A better solution: use an aluminum dibond plate and get it custom printed. The details are discussed in [this thread](http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/Calibration-Plate-td1830575.html).

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We took a cardboard sheets attached together, cut pieces of black and white blocks as per size 108 mm. and to make it straight and stable we attached ply wood around the cardboard from back side. I am sure there are good ways to do this but this process worked for us.

---

Originally posted by [Prasad](https://answers.ros.org/users/61/prasad/) with karma: 79 on 2011-03-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have had good results with using aluminum dibond with a calibration pattern glued on. I go to [858 Graphics](http://www.858graphics.com/Dibond-Printing.html) (that link has pricing information, which is very reasonable for small boards) and just send them a PDF file with the calibration pattern. There are likely similar shops wherever you happen to live.

[This](http://ibotics.ucsd.edu/trac/stingray/browser/trunk/vision_port/generate_calibration_target.py) is a Python script I use to generate the PDF files I send to them. That script requires you to fiddle with the text placement a bit, but I've found it convenient to have the pattern details printed on the board so you don't forget the sizes a year from now.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2012-12-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We had the exact same problem in our lab back when I was a student, so a few of us started [calib.io](https://calib.io)

There, you can quickly generate a PDF calibration pattern [here](https://calib.io/pages/camera-calibration-pattern-generator), for prototyping, printing yourself locally or buy through us where we guarantee high quality boards.

---

Originally posted by [calib.io](https://answers.ros.org/users/35397/calib.io/) with karma: 31 on 2018-05-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3